# GUI very small on high DPI display

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I have created Phonegap + standard Twitter Bootstrap app for android. Everything works OK, but when I open app on phone with high DPI like HTC One S (1280x720 display), everything in GUI (including controls - buttons, inputs, ...) is very small and user gets bad UX. What can I do to make it look like on mobiles with standard DPI?
Meta looks like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Comment: How do the examples like http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/justified-nav.html look on your  high DPI? They only use ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it. I had to remove `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` which was copied from don't know where.